# RMI stubs and sublcassing

Tags: java, networking, rmi

I know stubs in RMI are deprecated but I would like to clear
a doubt I have about them:

Suppose I have a class `A` that implements RemoteObject and
a class `B` wich extends `A`, does a client class, on a remote machine, that wants to use a remote object of type `B` need both of the stubs for `A` and `B` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. They aren't deprecated.
2. No, you only need the stub corresponding to the actual object that you're using remotely.

Comment: Isn't generation of stubs using rmic deprecated and its use discouraged ?

Comment: It is obsoleted by dynamic stubs. You will not find the word 'deprecated' anywhere that I am aware of, or 'discouraged' either. If you have a citation, cite it.